# Accessing typescript compiled js from html

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp

I have seen a lot of questions that are similar but non of them are related to my issue.

We are updating some of our code to typescript and all is well and good.  In most cases its just exporting functions from one place and importing to another.

Here is some very simple code just for testing my scenario.

```
//test.ts
declare var x:any;
function test(){
console.log('hello');
}
```

Have a gulp task which runs using babelify and tsify and converts this into .js file which is used in html page.

Everything i do in the ts file works fine.  I can call the test function from other .ts files and it all works.

**My Only Issue**

Now what i want to do and can't seem to get it working is access test function or x from inside the HTML page as follows'

```
//index.htm
<script src="test.js"></script>
<script>
test();  //error: test:206 Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined
</script>
```

I believe this is a scoping issue as the generated js file has a closure and wondering what is the best way to make the var and function available to the HTML page.

```
//sample test.js generated by gulp
(function(){function r(e,n,t){function o(i,f){if(!n[i]){if(!e[i]){var c="function"==typeof require&&require;if(!f&&c)return c(i,!0);if(u)return u(i,!0);var a=new Error("Cannot find module '"+i+"'");throw a.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",a}var p=n[i]={exports:{}};e[i][0].call(p.exports,function(r){var n=e[i][1][r];return o(n||r)},p,p.exports,r,e,n,t)}return n[i].exports}for(var u="function"==typeof require&&require,i=0;i<t.length;i++)o(t[i]);return o}return r})()({1:[function(require,module,exports){
"use strict";

function testfunc() {
    alert('hello');
}

},{}]},{},[1]);
```

Again all works fine as long as I don't need to call the function or access var from HTML file.

**Tools**
Visual Studio, Gulp, Tsify, Vueify,babelify,browserify

Comment: Could you post the content of your compiled Javascript file here? Thanks :)

Comment: @AnyMoose Not a duplicate as I don't have issues linking files and all files work as expected.

Comment: Do you need jsquery? Do you load your jsquery.js before your .js file?
<script src="/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/test.js"></script>
https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2016/04/3-ways-to-solve-jquery-uncaught-reference-error-is-not-defined.html

Comment: @AnyMoose Appreciate the link and I do use jquery but have no issue with it loading as all jquery functionality is just fine.  To be clear I just can't run the function from the html or access the var, and thats pretty much it apart from that all good.

Comment: you need to remove whatever module configuration you are using in your tsconfig.json ( compilerOptions.module ). You also should not use 'declare' statements to declare variables, use only var,let or const .'declare' declares type definitions, and type definitions are not exported to Javascript  AT ALL...

Comment: @mpm I tried that but it breaks many things that are working right now.

Comment: Why do you call a js file??? <script src="test.js"></script>

Comment: @AnyMoose I am not calling a js file its just being loaded in a page.  That is how you load external js file  into a page.